# software or algorithms to detect grammar units in texts

Tags: algorithm, linguistics

I'm not sure this is the right fit for stackoverflow but maybe you guys would suggest where to put this question otherwise but here it is anyway. Suppose I have a few sentences of a text like this:

> John reads newspapers everyday. Right now he has just finished reading
>   one. He will read another one and might even read a small book
>   tomorrow.

This small extract contains the following grammar units:

1. present simple (reads)
2. present perfect (has finished)
3. future simple (will read)
4. modal verb `may`

Do you know of any software, algorithm or study that defines rules for identifying these grammar patterns?

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree) also if you are going to use Ruby than you can use [TreeTop](https://github.com/nathansobo/treetop) or find the equivalent parser in other programming language.

Answer (score 1):

NTLK is a natural language parser for python, it works by tagging words. You can look at some examples [here](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch09.html). It creates a [parse-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree), which are very useful for these types of problems.

I haven't seen it distinguish between simple and perfect, but it could be modified to do so.